# Carrierwave, Fog and URL Rewriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm storing images in Amazon S3 using Fog and Carrierwave. It returns a url like `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my_image.jpg.`

DNS entries have been set up so that `images.mysite.com` points to `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com.`

I want to adjust my views an APIs to use the `images.mysite.com/my_image.jpg` URL. Carrierwave, however, only spits out the Amazon based one. Is there a simple way to tell Carrierwave and/or Fog to use a different host for its URLs than normal? If not, how would I modify the uploader to spit it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come to find out that, as of June 6th, 2012, Amazon AWS does not support custom SSL certs, which makes this a moot point.